# How do i join tables, aggregate at same time and convert result to JSON within SQlite/PDO?

Tags: android, json, sqlite, join, pdo

i am trying to outsource a result-aggregation from Android to php. I have trouble to correctly build a query with a joining table and encode it with JSON afteron. I am trying to get a result on a vote which Hero is the coolest. So i got a table for the heroes, one for the users and a table where i put my Votes.
ok this is what i got:

---

### Table hero : id, name

### Table user : id, name

### Table vote : voteid, userId, heroId

---

i am getting my result of the vote by **aggregating every equal heroIds**, then **getting the proper hero-names from the hero-table** and then **send back a JSON-object** looking like this:

### {"vote":[{"voteid":"1","heroCount":"7","heroName":"Batman"},{"voteid":"1","heroCount":"3","heroName":"Aquaman"}]}

---

i am a bit clueless, as my sqlite-knowledge is pretty limited. this is what i got so far in my .php:

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:voting.sqlite');
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM vote');   //<---- how to do that correctly?
$stmt->execute();

$result['vote']=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json=json_encode($result);

echo $json;
```

anyone can give me some nice input? has been quite some time i am thinking on this and don't get it solved :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use an SQL GROUP BY clause, and a LEFT JOIN. Something like the following:

```
SELECT hero.name AS heroName, COUNT(vote.userId) AS heroCount 
    FROM vote LEFT JOIN hero ON vote.heroId = hero.id GROUP BY hero.id
```

If you substitute that for the SQL in your PHP code it will produce JSON output similar to your specification. `voteid` will be missing though. If `voteid` is the primary key of the `vote` table then it means nothing to have it in an aggregate result like that. There will be 7 `voteid`s in the Batman result.

Comment: that voteid is just for future implementations of identifying several different votes. i will try putting this into my code now. thx!!

Comment: nice it is working out now!! thx alot that saved me one hell of a time :D